# How to use imported list template

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, list-template

I have got a list template (.stp) which I have imported in my site by going to "Web Designer Galleries --> List templates" in Site Settings.

After that I went to Site Contents to create a new list based on this template but I don't see any option to create. All I see are default libraries like Custom List, Document Library, Picture Library etc.

Did I miss a step to enable this list template? I have also got an InfoPath form (.xsn) and I suspect it is related to it so unless I import that one, it won't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Activated "Team Collaboration Lists Feature" and it works now. It is important that this is set at the Site Collection level as well as the Site level. If you find that activating "Team Collaboration Lists Feature" does not show your "App", move to the Collection level and enable the same feature.

Answer (score 5):

Simple just go to Site Content -> Click on add an app -> on left top you can get search option then you can search by your list template name -> once you find click on that Template and create a list.

Answer (score 0):

Click on "Add an app" from the site action menu or in site contents. It will show the template name of the app in the "Apps you can add" section.

Comment: When I click on "Add an app" the only options I see are Document Library, Picture Library, Custom List, Asset Library, Access App and Import Spreadsheet. My list template is not there whose name is MMN.

Comment: What is the site template you have? Did you deactivate any activated features? What are the permissions you have on site?

Comment: The site is Publishing site with default features. I just created this site. I am logged in as Farm Admin.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer to this and thought I'd share:
You need to click on "Your Apps" under the Site Contents.  It has all the possible apps, not just the smaller list. See image I attached.You have to take a step above the "Apps you can Add" [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see ANY extra apps then your custom list will be there but the master page needs to include this code to show the extra apps in the first place:

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar" BlockElement="true" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
```

Make sure that code is included in your master page and the extra apps should appear in the "Apps you can add" section.

Answer (score 0):

ok so I saved a list template from SP 2010 and uploaded it into 2013 list gallery...just template with no data - I could not see it in the "Apps you can add" I found that my list view threshold was 5000 and once I increased it to 10 000 it appeared....so check your list view threshold